# Mantener valores en un checkbox Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net

Necesito mantener la información en un formulario con `input` de tipo `checkbox`:

```
<form class="form" method="post">

            <div class="block">

                <label class="container checkboxContainer">
                    Italia

                    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="IT" value="IT">
                    <span class="checkmark checkbox"></span>

                </label>

                <label class="container checkboxContainer">
                    Estadounidense

                    <input type="checkbox" name="US" value="US">
                    <span class="checkmark checkbox"></span>

                </label>

            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Enviar datos">

        </form>
```

No puedo hacer uso de **ASP.NET Forms** debido a que es un ejercicio académico y estas son las restricciones. Sólo puedo hacer uso de **Razor** para mantener los valores.

Mi problema reside en que si fueran de tipo texto, podría usar `Request.Form` para mantener los valores. En cambio los *checkbox* tienen la propiedad `checked` que es de tipo *boolean*, y no sé exactamente cómo manejarla.

```
        String it = Request["IT"];
        String us = Request["US"];
        String fr = Request["FR"];
        String sp = Request["ES"];
        String type = Request["tipo"];
        String[] country = new String[0];
        Int32 arrayIndex = 0;



        @*Si el valor que retorna el método Request es igual al valor que se quiere bucar en la base de datos,
            redimensionar el array y posteriormente introducir este valor en la posición especificada por la
            variable 'arrayIndex''*@

        if (it == "IT")
        {
            Array.Resize(ref country, country.Length + 1);
            country[arrayIndex] = it;
            arrayIndex++;
        }
        if (us == "US")
        {
            Array.Resize(ref country, country.Length + 1);
            country[arrayIndex] = us;
            arrayIndex++;
        }
        if (fr == "FR")
        {
            Array.Resize(ref country, country.Length + 1);
            country[arrayIndex] = fr;
            arrayIndex++;
        }
        if (sp == "ES")
        {
            Array.Resize(ref country, country.Length + 1);
            country[arrayIndex] = sp;
        }

        @*Consulta de linq enlanzando la tabla PEL_T_Peliculas y PEL_T_TipoPelicula. Where usando .Contains para filtrar por los elementos almacenados
            en el array 'String[] countries' *@

        var query = from PEL_T_Peliculas in dbDatos.PEL_T_Peliculas
                    join PEL_T_TipoPelicula in dbDatos.PEL_T_TipoPelicula
                       on PEL_T_Peliculas.idTipo equals PEL_T_TipoPelicula.IdTipo

                    where country.Contains(PEL_T_Peliculas.Pais) && type.Contains(PEL_T_TipoPelicula.Tipo)
                    select new { PEL_T_Peliculas.Titulo, PEL_T_Peliculas.Pais, PEL_T_TipoPelicula.Tipo };

        @*Si la consulta 'var query' no contiene elementos; lanzar mensaje de error. *@

        if (query.Count() == 0)
        {
            <p>No se han encontrado resultados con los criterios de búsqueda especificados</p>
        }
```

---

```
        String it = Request["IT"];
        String us = Request["US"];
        String fr = Request["FR"];
        String sp = Request["ES"];
        String type = Request["tipo"];
        String[] country = new String[0];
        Int32 arrayIndex = 0;



        @*Si el valor que retorna el método Request es igual al valor que se quiere bucar en la base de datos,
            redimensionar el array y posteriormente introducir este valor en la posición especificada por la
            variable 'arrayIndex''*@

        if (it == "IT")
        {
            Array.Resize(ref country, country.Length + 1);
            country[arrayIndex] = it;
            arrayIndex++;
        }
        if (us == "US")
        {
            Array.Resize(ref country, country.Length + 1);
            country[arrayIndex] = us;
            arrayIndex++;
        }
        if (fr == "FR")
        {
            Array.Resize(ref country, country.Length + 1);
            country[arrayIndex] = fr;
            arrayIndex++;
        }
        if (sp == "ES")
        {
            Array.Resize(ref country, country.Length + 1);
            country[arrayIndex] = sp;
        }

        @*Consulta de linq enlanzando la tabla PEL_T_Peliculas y PEL_T_TipoPelicula. Where usando .Contains para filtrar por los elementos almacenados
            en el array 'String[] countries' *@

        var query = from PEL_T_Peliculas in dbDatos.PEL_T_Peliculas
                    join PEL_T_TipoPelicula in dbDatos.PEL_T_TipoPelicula
                       on PEL_T_Peliculas.idTipo equals PEL_T_TipoPelicula.IdTipo

                    where country.Contains(PEL_T_Peliculas.Pais) && type.Contains(PEL_T_TipoPelicula.Tipo)
                    select new { PEL_T_Peliculas.Titulo, PEL_T_Peliculas.Pais, PEL_T_TipoPelicula.Tipo };

        @*Si la consulta 'var query' no contiene elementos; lanzar mensaje de error. *@

        if (query.Count() == 0)
        {
            <p>No se han encontrado resultados con los criterios de búsqueda especificados</p>
        }
```

Comment: De qué modo llega tu booleano? ¿por el modelo?  ¿viewbag? agregate ese dato a la pregunta por favor!

Comment: Adjunto mi código completo

Comment: pero si usas razor quiere decir que el proyecto es asp.net mvc?

Comment: Ese es mi problema, solamente puedo crear hojas con extensión cshtml de Razor en mis proyectos, sino fuera así todo sería más fácil.

Comment: pero cshtml es asp.net mvc, tienes que definir un Controller con action donde hacer el post y recibir los datos que apliquen el modelbinding

Answer (score 0):

Para recibir los datos en `asp.net mvc` debes realizar un `post` del `form` a un `action` del `controller`

[Model Binding](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/model-binding-in-asp.net-mvc)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al realizar el post la clase que definas del `model` mapea los datos que recibe del html.